# Mathematical modelling of wealth distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, economics

How is the mathematics in modelling of wealth distribution developed? What kind of mathematics is used and how accurately is it able to model this economic phenomena? An example is the Bouchard Mezard model.

If anybody is familiar with the article "Degree and wealth distribution in a network induces by wealth" by G.Lee and G.Kim some explanation to the processes behind the equations would be very much appreciated.

Any kind of information, sources or input of any kind is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is not a question about research in mathematics, and the users of this site are unlikely to have any useful answers; so the question will probably be closed.  You might have more luck at economics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That is natural applied math question. Distributions of wealth are related to Pareto distribution. No reason to close.

Comment: You may also wish to look up the Loresnz Curve and the Gini Coefficient - both standard measures of statistical dispersion, variously used for modelling income or wealth inequality.

Comment: The suitable mathematical model for wealth distribution likely depends very much on the underlying political or economical system -- so I doubt that as asked your question is sufficiently clear.

Comment: Wealth inequality is (arguably) the central issue of macroeconomics. Lions, the Fields medalist, has co-authored papers in macroeconomics on this, where standard workhorse macro models are cast as MFG.

Answer (score 6):

My favourite introduction to the modelling of wealth starts from physics rather than mathematics: [Statistical mechanics of money, wealth, and income](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.1518) by Yakovenko and Rosser. Their point is that for the majority of the population the dynamics of money is well described by equilibrium statistical mechanics.

> By analogy with the Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution of energy in physics,
>   it is shown that the probability distribution of money is exponential
>   for certain classes of models with interacting economic agents.
>   Money plays the role of energy, to the extent that it is a conserved quantity. Conservation of money in a closed system naturally leads to an exponential distribution of wealth, analogous to the Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution. This applies to the majority of the population. The power law [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) applies to the tail of the distribution, containing the most wealthy individuals. These results suggest that the presence of a power-law tail is a nonequilibrium effect that requires constant growth or inflation of the economy, but disappears for a closed system with conservation laws.

[image]

*“Money, it’s a gas.”* Pink Floyd, *Dark Side of the Moon*

Comment: There's zero economics, mathematical or otherwise, in the above answer.